# Generator Function Understanding in redux-saga workflow, yield

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

I think I am confused by the concept of generator function right now.

I remember the way generator function works is that

the next yield won't be called until we purposely call the iterator.next().

For example:

```
function* testing () {
     yield 1;
     yield 2;
     yield 3;
}

const iterator = testing();
```

We can only get the value of 1, 2 and 3 by doing iterator.next().

The above understanding is what I have right now. ( And Hopefully it's correct understanding)

However, when I do

```
function* getUsers() {
    try {
        const result = yield call(api.getUser);
        yield put(actions.getUsersSuccess({
            items: result.data.data
        }));
        console.log(result);

        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
        console.log("15");

    } catch(e) {

    }
}
```

and when i start the app, it dispatches getUsersRequest, then Saga Watcher receive this action, then call the worker getUsers. ( And Hopefully it's also correct understanding)

The code is here

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        **this.props.getUsersRequest();**
    }

    handleSubmit = ({firstName, lastName}) => {
        this.props.createUserRequest(firstName, lastName);
    };

    render() {
        const users = this.props.users;
        return (
            <div style={{margin: '0 auto', padding: '20px', maxWidth: '600px'}}>
                <NewUserForm onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}/>
                <UserList users = {users.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


function* watchGetUsersRequest() {
    yield takeEvery(actions.Types.GET_USERS_REQUEST, getUsers);
}
```

My question is why in the console we can see console.log("15")?

We never call getUser.next() on purpose.

Thank you for your kind response and help!

You can see the implmentation of Saga and App
https://github.com/Oliverlee1003/SagaList/blob/main/src/sagas/users.js
https://github.com/Oliverlee1003/SagaList/blob/main/src/components/App.js

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydzR7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"rmb"*?? Is that "remember"? Please write complete words, use proper punctuation and capitalization, etc., so that your question is clear to the people trying to read it.

Comment: *"We can only get the value of 2 and 3 by doing iterator.next()."* No, the first result object from `next` will have `.value == 1`. The next will have 2, the next will have 3. See https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/03c6ywna/ Why would you expect the first one to be skipped?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code that is executing `getUsers()`. I don't know you expect us to help you otherwise.

Comment: Thanks T.J. and Mario's suggestions. I've already refine the post.

1. rmb is remeber.
2. the first result object from next will have .value == 1. That is correct, the first one should not be skipped.

3.  The App class dispatches the action by ```this.props.getUsersRequest(); ``` then the Saga watchers call ```getUsers() ```by ``` function* watchGetUsersRequest()```

Comment: The redux-saga framework will take care of iterating over your sagas - so you don't need to call next() yourself.

Comment: See the notes for middleware.run() here https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#middlewarerunsaga-args

Comment: Thank you so much@IAmDranged. I think this helps to understand my question!
Do you mind if I putting your comment as the solution in this post?

Comment: You're welcome. Please do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @IAmDranged

Here's answer from him

> The redux-saga framework will take care of iterating over your sagas - so you don't need to call next() yourself.

> See the notes for middleware.run() here redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#middlewarerunsaga-args